# Javascript: How to add text at runtime on a variable number of labels at HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox and a label side by side in an html. Depending on the number of output returned from server side, there can be any number of checkbox and label. For example, if 5 outputs are returned from the server, there will be 5 rows (each row is 1 checkbox and 1 label).

The text to be displayed on the label is a variable and generated at runtime depending on what the database returns. Using below code, I can show 5 rows of checkbox and label. How do I update the text at `id="labelFollowup"` at runtime so that instead of `label` it shows a new text runtime?

```
$(function(){
  let div = '<div class ="followupSteps">'+
  '<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFollowup">'+
  '<label for="checkboxFollowup" id="labelFollowup">label</label>'+
  '</div>';
  for(var index=0; index<5; index++)
    {
      $('table').append('<tr> <td>'+div+' </td> </tr>')
     }
});
```

And on the html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should make your ids for labels and inputs unique. Try this:

```js
$(function(){
  let data = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
  for(var index=0; index<5; index++)
    {
    let div = '<div class ="followupSteps">'+
  '<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFollowup'+index+'">'+
  '<label for="checkboxFollowup'+index+'" id="labelFollowup'+index+'">'+data[index]+'</label>'+
  '</div>';
    
    
      $('table').append('<tr> <td>'+div+' </td> </tr>')
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: instead of hardcoding '1' here $('#labelFollowup1').text('hi');, how can I do that without hardcode, only depending on whatever the index value is?

Comment: @lilyhack it's just an example. I don't know where do you want to change these labels. Do you want to do it right in the loop?

Comment: yes, however it works, I have the data available when I am in the loop. I just dont want to show those hardcoded label, need to show the data that I get from database.

Comment: @lilyhack why don't you show an example of what you're talking? You're mentioning some server outputs without showing any example.

Comment: Don't append inside for loops. Use string concatenation instead and append only once outside.

Comment: This is REALLY heavy. It creates a new string every time it goes through the loop. This isn't necessary and adds significant processing... in the long run it's better to make templates strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  const div = '<div class ="followupSteps">'+
  '<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFollowup-{{labelId}}">'+
  '<label for="checkboxFollowup" id="labelFollowup">label {{labelId}}</label>'+
  '</div>';
  const tr = '<tr> <td>'+div+'</td> </tr>';
  const rows = new Array(5).fill(tr).map((tr, index) => tr.replace(/{{labelId}}/g, index+1)).join("");
  $('table').append(rows)
});
```

`label 1
label 2
label 3
label 4
label 5`